# Installing and including envisage plugin

Tags: python, plugins

I just installed the `envisagecore` and `envisageplugin` in `Ubuntu 10.04`. I'm using `Eclipse SDK` and `PyDev plugin`. How can I import this plugin in Eclipse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have access to the Envisage plugins documentation, so I'm not sure how these are installed. In general what you need to do is open Windows -> Preferences -> PyDev -> Interpreter - Python and check that the package directory is present in the System PYTHONPATH window. If it isn't add it and press Apply.

If your plugins are installed in a standard location, i.e. site-packages, another option is to remove your current interpreter from the upper window and press Auto Config.